# Croppie image uploaded by jquery ajax is not in the submitted request

Tags: jquery, ajax, croppie

I'd like to use the Croppie plugin to crop, resize and upload a profile picture to my laravel app. Unfortunately when I'm trying to upload the resulted image using a jQuery ajax, it is not included in the request submitted as far as I can tell. Please see the code below. What am I doing wrong?

from my blade.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('node_modules/croppie/croppie.css') }}" />
<script src="{{ URL::asset('node_modules/croppie/croppie.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
    });
    
    
    var mycroppie = $('#profile-image-holder').croppie({
        enableExif: true,
        enableOrientation: true,    
        viewport: {  
            width: 200,
            height: 250,
            type: 'square' 
        },
        boundary: {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        }
    });
    
    
    $('#image-browser').on('change', function () { 
      var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          mycroppie.croppie('bind',{
            url: e.target.result
          }).then(function(){
            console.log('jQuery bind complete');
          });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    });

    $('#register').on('click', function (ev) {
      mycroppie.croppie('result', {
        type: 'base64',
        size: 'viewport',
        format: 'jpeg'
      }).then(function (img) {
        console.log(img);
        $.ajax({
          url: "{{route('office.guide-reg-step3.store', $hash)}}",
          type: "POST",
          data: {"image":img},
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success:function(data){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
      });
    });
    
    
</script>
```

This is what I get when I print out the request sent to my laravel app:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#43 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#373 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure() {#382 ▶}
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44 ▶}
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#51 ▶}
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#47 ▶}
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#48 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#46 ▶}
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#49 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/de/guide-reg-step3/faeb1ade9a29bd12cd3046e446c85435"
  #requestUri: "/de/guide-reg-step3/faeb1ade9a29bd12cd3046e446c85435"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: Illuminate\Session\Store {#439 ▼
    #id: "Tti26xaxCNLU5tz6p9e9t00WsxbnyxeJs4x0CSCq"
    #name: "gonativeguide_session"
    #attributes: array:3 [▼
      "_token" => "WX2o6FqdPWQGtoOmg8ZJ6nJ1SofgYVbMLPEq21U9"
      "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
      "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    #handler: Illuminate\Session\FileSessionHandler {#438 ▶}
    #started: true
  }
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -preferredFormat: null
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  -isSafeContentPreferred: null
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

As you can see the files are empty, and there is no "image" section either...
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
W.

Answer (score 0):

It is not uploaded as a file. It is sent as a parameter.
You can access the data as follows.

```
$image = $request-> input('image');
```